# Mexican palm tree boot trimming

Tags: trees, palm

While I can show that trimming the boots off a mexican palm tree is done by hand*, I'm trying to think why on some only the upper half is done, another only a small section is done, while others around them are fully done. Here is an image showing what I'm talking about:

[image]

Any ideas?

*: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-xPBq_wowvs

Answer (score 1):

It just looks like they did not get to them. Best practice for trimming a palm tree is to remove all dead fronds/ leaves and any health fronds hanging below the horizon line. Anything above should stay. The ones in the above picture that have been done look fine.